# Can't start CAKeyframeAnimation in the middle

Tags: ios, macos, core-animation, calayer

I'm creating an interactive animation on macOS (but iOS also applicable) by setting the `speed` to `0` and adjusting the `timeOffset` between `0` and `1` during user interaction.

This works fine, but I'd like the start position to be in the middle - so I have the `timeOffset` set initially to `0.5`. The problem is that now the `timeOffset` range is set to `0.5` to `1.5` for some reason. Is this a bug in `CoreAnimation`?

Comment: Are you saying the range from 0.5 to 1.5 is required to **just** play back the second half of the animation? Or that it takes it until 1.5 to start in the middle, play to the end, loop back to the beginning, and play up until the middle again?

Answer (score 1):

Core Animation should be consistent between macOS and iOS, but I can only speak to iOS.

`timeOffset` is not a normalized value. That is, it's not always from 0 to 1. It's just a literal time offset from the `beginTime` of that animation, which is 0 by default. Depending the duration of your animation, the fill mode, and the repeat count (or repeat duration), this is expected.

The behavior I would expect, in your example, assuming the animation duration is 1.0 seconds, would be for it to start at the halfway point at `timeOffset` 0.5, continue until the end of the animation at `timeOffset` 1.0, snap back to the start of the animation, and continue up until just before the middle of the animation at `timeOffset` 1.5.

So yes, this is expected behavior, and it's not likely to be a bug. (As a side note, I have encountered no actual bugs in Core Animation over my 7 years of using it. It's very solid.)